# Create a usable reference for a whole column using a formula

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, reference, match

I have a spreadsheet where I need a reference to a whole column, but the location on the column is not determined ahead of time, so I used INDEX MATCH, ADDRESS, and CELL functions to find that out. Once I find the right column I need to reference cells in it.

Two problems stop me:

- I have columns that have words or letters as data, and columns with numbers as data.
- I need to reference whole column simply, because the amount of rows is varying as well.
- The formula I tried doesn't work, it just lets me view the location.

I tried using the below formula, and got the output I wanted, but it merely just displays the address, and when I place it in a formula, it doesn't work.
I needed something that I could use as a reference in a formula.

Formula for State

```
=LEFT(ADDRESS(7,CELL("col",INDEX('Extracted Sales Data (2)'!B7:AI200000,1,MATCH("*"&"Ship"&"*"&"State"&"*",'Extracted Sales Data (2)'!B7:AI7,0))),4,1,"Extracted Sales Data"),28)&":"&LEFT(ADDRESS(7,CELL("col",INDEX('Extracted Sales Data (2)'!B7:AI200000,1,MATCH("*"&"Ship"&"*"&"State"&"*",'Extracted Sales Data (2)'!B7:AI7,0))),4,1),1)
```

Formula for Revenue Amount

```
=LEFT(ADDRESS(7,CELL("col",INDEX('Extracted Sales Data (2)'!B7:AI200000,1,MATCH("*"&"Rev"&"*"&"Am"&"*",'Extracted Sales Data (2)'!B7:AI7,0))),4,1,"Extracted Sales Data"),28)&":"&LEFT(ADDRESS(7,CELL("col",INDEX('Extracted Sales Data (2)'!B7:AI200000,1,MATCH("*"&"Rev"&"*"&"Am"&"*",'Extracted Sales Data (2)'!B7:AI7,0))),4,1),1)
```

The above formula returns the below values, but I can't use it as a reference.(Note that the columns are not pre-determined)

State Column

```
'Extracted Sales Data'!G:G
```

Revenue Amount column:

```
'Extracted Sales Data'!AQ:AQ
```

I'm trying to use it in SUMIF and COUNTIF functions.

```
=SUMIF('Extracted Sales Data'!G:G,M16,'Extracted Sales Data'!AQ:AQ)
```

or

```
=COUNTIF('Extracted Sales Data'!G:G,M16)
```

Sample Data:

One type of data set:

```
Ship-to-State          Trx Type     RC Revenue Amount
Alabama                INVOICE      50000 
California             INVOICE      3000
```

Another type of data set

```
Customer          Ship to State          Trx Type     Expense Amount     Revenue Amount
Customer A        Alabama                INVOICE      21000              50000 
Customer B        California             INVOICE      1680               3000
```

I need to have one formula for both data sets, how do I achieve this? (Reference whole column based on a lookup/match.)

Comment: Post some sample data which will help to get better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Harun24HR. I have added sample data for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You only need the INDEX/MATCH parts:

```
INDEX('Extracted Sales Data (2)'!B7:AI200000,0,MATCH("*"&"Rev"&"*"&"Am"&"*",'Extracted Sales Data (2)'!B7:AI7,0))
```

With the `0` in the second criterion it will return the full column.

So then you would just use those in the formulas:

```
=SUMIF(INDEX('Extracted Sales Data (2)'!B7:AI200000,0,MATCH("*"&"Ship"&"*"&"State"&"*",'Extracted Sales Data (2)'!B7:AI7,0)),M16,INDEX('Extracted Sales Data (2)'!B7:AI200000,0,MATCH("*"&"Rev"&"*"&"Am"&"*",'Extracted Sales Data (2)'!B7:AI7,0)))
```

And do the same with the COUNTIF

Comment: I'll try this out. Maybe I was thinking too much

Comment: This worked great! Thanks so much for the help!